# show and hide div is not working according to drop down selected value in Asp.net using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have three div that are hidden i have to show them according to the selection of drop Down but its not working What i am doing Wrong?

> my dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPermissionMode" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="25px">
     <asp:ListItem>choose</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Individual</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Group</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

> my divs

```
 <div class="choose box row text-center">
      Select A permission Mode if you want to give This user a  <strong>permission</strong>
  </div>
 <div class="Individual row box">
                           l
 </div>
  <div class="Group row box">
       You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here
 </div>
```

script

```
<%-- <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#ddlPermissionMode").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selectedValue").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
    </script>
```

style

```
<style>
        .box{
        color: #fff;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
     .choose{ background: #ff0000; }
     .Individual{ background: #228B22; }
     .Group{ background: #0000ff; }
    </style>--%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `$(this).find("option:selectedValue")` to `$(this).find("option:selected")`

Everything seems fine just change your script like this

```
<%-- <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#ddlPermissionMode").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
    </script>
```